# Checking the font properties of a text in Java

Tags: java, fonts, awt, text-styling

I am developing an `IDE` for which I need a help. Suppose you have inserted a `JLabel` (with a text) in the container. Now, how do I check whether the text of the `JLabel` is underlined, strikedthrough and sub-(or super-)scripted?

We know that for checking for Bold and Italic styles, we have the `isBold()` and `isItalic()` methods of the `Font` class. How can we do the same for `UNDERLINE`, `STRIKETHROUGH`, `SUPERSCRIPT` and `SUBSCRIPT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used `java.awt.font.TextAttribute` to achieve the styling you can check with

```
 Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
 boolean underlined = attributes.containsKey(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE);
```